# Zoom affects MacBook Pro M1 16" sound quality even if Zoom is not running

Tags: macbook-pro, ventura, zoom, zoom.app

Sometimes the sound quality (for example music sound) of my MacBook Pro M1 16" becomes very bad. And only one solution for me is to start Zoom, wait when it will load and quit Zoom. After that the sound becomes normal again.

My OS: MacOs Ventura Version 13.2.1

Can it be fixed somehow?

Comment: Sound quality in general, or are you using Bluetooth?

Comment: no, USB headphones

Comment: Define 'bad'. Crackly? Low volume? Distorted? What else have you tried? Switching to built-in speakers and back?

Comment: @benwiggy sound without low frequencies. I tried to kill coreaudiod, didn't help