# Sound randomly disappears in USB headphones on MacBook Pro M1 16"

Tags: macbook-pro, headphones, ventura

Sound randomly disappears in USB headphones on my MacBook Pro M1 16". It doesn't depend on headphones or USB-C connector, I tried different. And the sound appears only after unplugging headphones and plugging back again.

My OS: MacOs Ventura Version 13.2.1

How can I troubleshoot?

Comment: Have you tried all the USB-C ports on the MBP? Are the USB headphones equipped with a USB-C connector, or are you using an adapter? Are there other devices (external monitors, USB-C hubs, USB-C external storage drives connected? If there are other devices connected, disconnect them and see if the headphones disconnect. Please indicate the brand and model of USB headphones.

Comment: This would appear to be linked to https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/455031/85275

Comment: @IconDaemon as I wrote I tried different headphones (Jabra, Sennheizer, both work perfectly with PC) and different USB-C hubs. Also it was with extranal monitor and without.

Comment: From where we all sit elsewhere on this planet, it is hard to diagnose the problem. Have you done any research on this particular brand & model of headphones to make sure they're compatible with macOS? Although it sounds ridiculous that something as simple as headphones work sporadically on macOS, but work fine on Windows, it is not uncommon.